# Mysql create view with count clause

Tags: mysql

In my db I've a table (t1) with this structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 't1' (
'id_ric' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'id_tipoins' decimal(1,0) NOT NULL,
'datains' timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY ('id_ric')
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I create a view to count all record grouped by id_user in this way

```
CREATE VIEW view_users_app
AS
SELECT  id_user, MAX(datains) last_datains, COUNT(*) totalCount 
FROM    t1
GROUP   BY id_user
```

Now I'd like also count where id_tipoins = 1 and id_tipoins = 2 (grouped by id_user).
It's possible to do? How could I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW view_users_app
AS
SELECT  id_user, 
        MAX(datains) last_datains, 
        COUNT(*) totalCount,
        sum(id_tipoins = 1) as p1,
        sum(id_tipoins = 2) as p2
FROM    t1
GROUP   BY id_user
```